# Differential equation solution transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose that we have the following non-lienar homogeneous differential equation, that is

$$ay^{'}(x)+by(x)y^{'}(x)-y(x)=0$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}-{0}$ constants. Considering that $y^{'}\neq0$ the d.e. is written equilevantely as follows

$$a\frac{y^{'}(x)}{y(x)}+by^{'}(x)-1=0\Rightarrow a\ln|y(x)|+by(x)-x=C$$
where $C$ is a constant. Supposing that $y(x)<0$ (or positive) is there any transformation that can give an exact solution $y(x)$? We further asssume that $y(\cdot)$ is a decreasing and continuous differentiable function of $x$.

Comment: You could use the Lambert-W function, but that is mostly only giving a name to the (normalized form of the) equation, not really a simplification.

Comment: Well, you mean that, since for $y<0$ it holds that
$$(-y(x))^a(exp\{by(x)\})=\exp\{x+C\}$$
I can use this type of transformation...that you call it Lambert-W function...I have never heard of that...

Comment: @Aryadeva and Lutz Lehmann maybe my question is silly, but is there any chance to solve this d.e. by using linear transformations? Or the solution is not going to change...

Comment: No, this is so non-linear that no simplification exists. Divide first by $a$ so that $-ye^{\frac ba y}=ce^{\frac xa}$, then normalize to $\frac ba ye^{\frac ba y}=-\frac{cb}ae^{\frac xa}$ and then $\frac ba y=W(-\frac{cb}ae^{\frac xa})$, select a branch $W_0$ or $W_{-1}$ that fits the situation.

Comment: What is this branch intuition? I understand tha we talk about a type of a function that if I use $W_0$ or $W_{-1}$ I will be in different branch of the function, but how can I know which one? If I am mistaken feel free to correct me!

Comment: As Lutz said you have the Lambert function to express y..as a function of x. @HungerLearn